# Using cancancan's check_authorization with devise with custom controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, ruby-on-rails-6, cancancan

**TL;DR** (full question below)

cancan comes with `check_authorization` which lets you know if you forgot to add authorisation to any part of your app. Essentially, I just want to know if it's necessary to add authorisation to the 'devise' part of an app - or does devise do everything it needs to out of the box? (i.e. it would be extremely bad if one user could change another user's password, for example! - does that need to be prevented via cancan, or does devise ensure that already out of the box?)

**Full question**

I have devise and cancancan set up, everything seems to work.

When I added `check_authorization`, everything continued to work, except logging in and out doesn't work any more

```
CanCan::AuthorizationNotPerformed in Devise::SessionsController#destroy
This action failed the check_authorization because it does not authorize_resource. Add skip_authorization_check to bypass this check.
Extracted source (around line #266):
264
265
266
267
268
269
              
          next if options[:unless] && controller.send(options[:unless])

          raise AuthorizationNotPerformed,
                'This action failed the check_authorization because it does not authorize_resource. '\
                'Add skip_authorization_check to bypass this check.'
        end
```

Curiously, when a user updates their information, that works fine (no error)

Any ideas / pointers greatly appreciated

Also, should I be `skip_authorization_check` on devise controllers? Although the error message suggests it, it sounds risky

Lastly, I don't exactly know how to access the devise controllers in order to add `skip_authorization_check`. Here is my directory (using users controllers for devise)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you don't have to worry about `skip_authorization_check` on the devise controllers.

And in case you get this error message for any other controllers:

```rb
CanCan::AuthorizationNotPerformed (This action failed the check_authorization because it does not authorize_resource. Add skip_authorization_check to bypass this check.):
```

then the solution is to either

1. add authorization to that resource (or parts thereof) that require it, OR
2. simply skip authorization checks if a resource doesn't require authorization.

Authorization checks can be skipped by adding this to the resource

```rb
skip_authorization_check
```

And you can use `only` or `except` like so

```rb
skip_authorization_check except: [:index]
```

and

```rb
skip_authorization_check only: [:show, :edit]
```